# Vue / Vuetify bind image from api dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want to bind an image dynamically to my `<v-img>` component.

```
<template>
  <v-img
    id="image"
    :src=backgroundImage
    aspect-ratio="1"
    class="grey lighten-2"
  >
  </v-img>
</template>
```

In my script I am loading a default image, on call a route in the mounted methods which gives me randomly an image from a server. The request works and I successfully get an image url which works.
But I am unable to bind it to my image src.

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    backgroundImage: 'https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg'
  },

  mounted () {
    setBgImg();
  },

  methods: {
    // get random background image 
    async setBgImg() {
      const route = 'http://localhost:4000/api/image/random';
      const { data } = await axios.get(route);

      this.backgroundImage = data[0].image;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Edit forgot to paste the error message, here it is:

```
> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'backgroundImage' in undefined
```

Comment: can you provide the data result from `axios.get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things which need an update.

First data needs to return an object in vue:

```
    export default {
        data: () => ({
        backgroundImage: ''
    }),
```

Second of all you need to call the `setBgImg()` method using `this`:

```
      mounted () {
        this.setBgImg();
      },
```

After that you should be able to show the given image from the api:

```
      <v-img
        id="image"
        :src="backgroundImage"
        aspect-ratio="1"
        class="grey lighten-2"
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check from console of Chrome Dev Tools, you should see some error based on above code that this.backgroundImage is undefined

The data () method should return an object

```
data () {
    return {
       backgroundImage: 'https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg'
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to paste the error message I updated the question